# What size wire do I need to run for 10 100 amp Rv hookup with individual breakers off a 400 amp service at 420 feet to the last pole?

Tags: electrical

400 amp service
10 RV breakered 100 amp pedestals 
20 ft apart
420 feet to last pedestal
What size wire?

Comment: I don't have my code book handy but first RV are 50/ 30/ 20/15 amp depending on the park space. Next this is not a DIY question because this is a commercial question. Check out rv's and RV parks in the code as the required ampacity has changed in the 17 code. VTC

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because commercial is not DIY a license is required.

Comment: What is a 100A RV hookup? Are you thinking because it's 2 legs of 50A that it's 100A?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is well outside the scope of DIY.SE.

Answer (score 1):

You should aim to keep voltage drop under 5% or close to it.

Given the voltage drop and statutory requirements, you'd be best to run at least 750 or 800 kcmil aluminum wire.  At 320A actual flow, you'll have 3.7% voltage drop for the 240' from the supply to the first RV stand.

Using copper wire for such a large run is a waste of money, aluminum is fine for feeder.

You would not be able to splice such large wire to an RV stand directly, so you should come into a distribution panel there, or a little past there.  From there, branch to the various stands.  Each 50A stand *must* have at least #6 copper or #4 aluminum wire, and I would bump 2 sizes for every 100'.  If you want 2 stands back to back for 100A, try #1 aluminum.   You can run it through a [voltage drop calculator](https://www.southwire.com/support/voltage-drop-calculator.htm) to see What wire to use for a particular voltage drop.   The calculator I linked doesn't do very well with 400A circuits, but it's fine in the numbered cable ranges.